# How to add intellisense in Visual Studio Code for custom angularjs module?

Tags: angularjs, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to add intellisense support for my custom modules/services?

I've found article on [how to add intellisense for AngularJS API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/05/22/getting-started-with-angular-and-visual-studio-code.aspx), but didn't find any, how to create one for modules and services which are private for my project.

I am using Visual Studio Code v 0.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most ways of "adding intellisense for AngularJS" in VS Code only adds intellisense for stock angular directives. Your own methods / properties inside custom services won't be added to this, which is really annoying... Visual Studio 2015 supports this natively, and there is a plugin for Visual Studio 2013 to do the same – nothing yet for VS Code, as far as I know.

Comment: This is truly sad. For an IDE that's so beautiful and efficient, this is a major setback